# How to prevent rendering of a specific item in the <apex:repeat> loop?

Tags: apex, repeat, rendered

I have the following code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="false">
    <apex:repeat value="{!Proposals}" var="item">
        <li>
            <a href="{!$Page.aa_rg_jm_proposal}?id={!item.Proposal.ID}">{!item.Proposal.Name}</a> 
            <span class="ui-li-count">{!item.LineCount}</span>
        </li>
    </apex:repeat>
</ul>
```

I want to prevent a line item (e.g. `<li>..<li>`) from being rendered if `item.LineCount = 0`.

I tried adding a `rendered` attribute to the `<apex:repeat>` tag like so:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Proposals}" var="item" 
    rendered="{!IF(item.LineCount > 0, true, false)}">
```

but it won't take it.

Is there a way to achieve something like this in visualforce?

P.S.  I am aware that I can easily filter the collection in the controller, but I want to know if there is a way to do it the way I outlined.

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't take it"? Are you getting an error or is it just not working? Is LineCount an integer?

Comment: @MikeChale I should have said, it doesn't have the desired effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you just need to wrap the output in something you can render selectively such as an outputpanel.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="false">
    <apex:repeat value="{!Proposals}" var="item">
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!item.LineCount > 0}">
            <li>
                <a href="{!$Page.aa_rg_jm_proposal}?id={!item.Proposal.ID}">{!item.Proposal.Name}</a> 
                <span class="ui-li-count">{!item.LineCount}</span>
            </li>        
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:repeat>
</ul>
```

Comment: This produces the intended result, but it also wraps a `span` tag around each `<li>` and completely messes up the styling.  Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: yes, take a look at the layout attribute for outputpanels in the visualforce api documentation, there are a couple options you have to control what the resulting html is, include no html

Comment: Perfect.  `layout="none"` did the trick.  Thanks a bunch!